# Intallation Error, How to Fix

Tags: 16.04

I had Windows on this Computer for a while but I have decided to go back to Ubuntu. However, I'm having trouble installing the operating system. I always get this same error: [image: Ubuntu_Error] I have no idea what to do here or how to proceed.I am attempting to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode from a live cd. Just Ubuntu.Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please describe with more details what you have and what you want! It seems you are trying to install in UEFI mode. Am I right about this? Is this what you want? Do you want a dual boot system? Do you try automatic or manual partitioning (alias 'Something else')? What partition table is there on the internal drive (MSDOS (MBR) or GUID (GPT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Backup

Before going ahead, make sure that you have backed up all important data from the internal drive.

### Create a new partition table

There might be problems because of some data (on the internal drive).

- Boot from the Ubuntu live/install drive (USB or DVD). (Boot in UEFI mode, because you want to install in UEFI mode.)
- Wipe the first mibibyte of the internal drive. You can do this manually and risky with **`dd`** or safer if you install **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**.
- Start **`gparted`** and create a new partition table. You can select both the standard MSDOS partition table and the modern GUID partition table, GPT. Particularly if it is a big drive, or you want to have many partitions, it is better with GPT.
- Set up partitions if you wish. It is easier with `gparted` than with the installer.

### Start the installer

- Start the installer and select automatic partitioning or manual partitioning 'Something else'.
- In UEFI mode, the installer will create the EFI system partition (which is the UEFI bootloader) in the first drive, `/dev/sda`, automatically (no matter what you tell it to do).

### Detailed help

The following links to the ISO testing tracker may help,

- [Ubuntu Desktop amd64 testcases in Xenial 16.04.1](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126272/testcases)
- [Install (entire disk)](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126272/testcases/1300/results)
- [Install (manual partitioning)](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126272/testcases/1302/results)